# Multiple namespace declaration in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

Is it legal to replace something like this:

```
namespace foo {
   namespace bar {
      baz();
   }
}
```

with something like this:

```
namespace foo::bar {
   baz();
}
```

?

Comment: what is it that you trying to achieve by this?

Comment: This works in c++17.

Comment: You'll see it after 7 years from the time of asking :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can combine namespaces into one name and use the new name (i.e. Foobar).

```
namespace Foo { namespace Bar {
    void some_func() {
        printf("Hello World.");
    }
}}

namespace Foobar = Foo::Bar;

int main()
{
    Foobar::some_func();
}
```

Comment: another unnecessary, confusing functionality.

Answer (score 23):

**Pre C++17**:

No, it's not. Instead of a bunch of indented nested namespaces, it's certainly valid to put them on the same line:

```
namespace Foo { namespace Bar { namespace YetAnother {
    // do something fancy
} } } // end Foo::Bar::YetAnother namespace
```

**C++17 Update**:

[You can now nest namespaces more cleanly in C++17](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html):

```
namespace Foo::Bar::YetAnother {
  // do something even fancier!
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone wondering, the form `namespace foo::bar` is supported since C++17. References:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace
- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4230.html

Answer (score 5):

Qualified names, like `something::someting_else` in C++ can only be used to refer to entities that have already been declared before. You cannot use such names to introduce something previously unknown. Even if the nested namespace was already declared before, extending that namespace is also considered as "introducing something new", so the qualified name is not allowed.

You can use such names for defining functions previously declared in the namespace

```
namespace foo {
  namespace bar {
    int baz();
  }
}

// Define
int foo::bar::baz() {
  /* ... */
}
```

but not declaring new namespaces of extending existing ones.

Answer (score 4):

No; it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try it? Visual C++ gives me the following errors:

> 1>C:\...\foo.cpp(31): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'bar'
>   1>C:\...\fooo.cpp(31): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

Comment: Note: Just because something works or does not work with a particular compiler does not mean it's standards or not standards compliant.

Comment: @Billy: Something working does not mean anything. Something *not* working does. If your compiler doesn't support a feature, then you can't use it, whatever the standard says on the subject.

Comment: @Dennis: While this is true, the OP didn't ask for whether or not his or her compiler would support it, (s)he asked if it was valid.

Answer (score 0):

As per the grammar in $2.10, an identifier cannot have the token `":"`. So the name `foo::bar` is ill-formed.

Comment: That doesn't mean much, without also showing that an identifier is needed here. `foo::bar` is obviously valid sometimes.