# namespace in namespace in C++

Tags: c++

This code produces the following compilation error: **‘MyClass’ in namespace ‘MyNameSpace2::MyNameSpace1’ does not name a type**

```
namespace MyNameSpace1 {
    class MyClass {
    };
}

namespace MyNameSpace2 {
    namespace MyNameSpace1 {
    }

    MyNameSpace1::MyClass a;
}


int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

But removing empty namespace

```
namespace MyNameSpace1 {
}
```

resolves the compilation error. Removing outter namespace also eleminates the compilation error. It looks like namespace in namespace has special semantics restricting compiler from searching identifiers out of outter namespace for the code **below** the inner namespace! What a wierd rule? Can you please explain or share a link to detailed explanation on the topic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to access `MyNameSpace1` from global namespace instead of `MyNameSpace1` from `MyNameSpace2` then you can do it explicitly `::MyNameSpace1::MyClass a;`. It does not work as is because name `MyNameSpace1` in your example refers directly to `MyNameSpace1` from `MyNameSpace2`, that is `MyNameSpace1` in `MyNameSpace2` *shadows* `MyNameSpace1` from global namespace.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589204/multiple-namespace-declaration-in-c